# ng-cloak is not stopping the flickering of element

Tags: angularjs, ngcloak

I am getting the flickering of content. Trying to resolve it by using **ng-cloak** but that's not working. I have one main view and multiple templates for separate views. My main view includes

```
<section id="ng-app">
<div ui-view ng-cloak></div>
</section>
```

I added ng-cloak here and in CSS

```
[ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], [data-ng-cloak], [x-ng-cloak], .ng-cloak, .x-ng-cloak {
  display: none !important;
}
```

But inspite of this, the flickering is still there. Do I need to include ng-cloak separately in all the template files? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Did you place the `ng-cloak` css in the top of your `head` ?

Comment: You don't have to add a css for ng-cloak to work.

Comment: @MartijnWelker yes,at the top of the file.